# Huffmann Code for the given frequency set

Tags: data-structures, huffman-code, compression

To generate the Huffman code for given set of frequencies.
{1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 12, 21}

According to my understanding we generate the huffmann code for a given problem according to the frequency (times a symbol occurs) and thus calculating the freqency so the table for the above set would be this :-

[Probability Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tg9T.jpg)

Then I tried to make the frequency tree but I am stuck anyone mind helping me a little bit ?

Comment: Nobody can help me with this?

Comment: Seems you already have frequencies: 21 instances of H and so on. So use tree building algorithm described in any book or article - join two smallest nodes until all nodes are used.

Comment: @MBo 21 is given in set and it occurs one hence frequency is "1" not 21 i think

Comment: You can show initial problem formulation to be sure in meaning `set of frequencies`. In any case, algo is simple and widely described.

Comment: No, you do not generate probabilities of the occurrences of frequency values. The frequencies are counts of how many times each symbol has occurred, and themselves represent probabilities (which you don't need to calculate either). Simply apply the Huffman algorithm, which can be found in a thousand places, to that list of frequencies.

Comment: What's the difference between code and item in the linked image? Why do you have both?